# PHP router and nginx configuration

Tags: php, nginx, router, nginx-location

I have made a php website without framework and I've used the router of https://grafikart.fr/tutoriels/router-628 !
With Apache and a .htaccess all is ok++ but unfortunately I have to use nginx !

My index.php is:

```
<?php

if ($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'fr')
    include './src/lang/fr.php';
else
    include './src/lang/en.php';

require './vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new App\Router\Router($_GET['url']);

include './src/views/layouts/header.php';

$router->get('/', "Home#show");
$router->get('/mention', "Mention#show");
$router->get('/office/:id', "Offices#show");
$router->get('/meeting/:id', "Meetings#show");

$router->post('/contact', "Contact#send");


include './src/views/layouts/footer.php';

$router->run();
```

And when a route is call, my controller look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class HomeController
{

    public function show()
    {
        include './src/views/home/index.php';
    }
}
```

For my nginx config, I have to redirect all URL to my index.php !
I found :

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

or:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; #if doesn't exist, send it to index.php
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:<PORT>;
 }
```

But all my research failed :(

Someone have any idea to witch config I have to do for my router work

Thank :)

Comment: `$args` and `$query_string` are just different names for the same variable. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_query_string).